# Pros and cons of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance, database

Could anybody tell me what is the pros and cons of mongodb, especially comparing with the relational database? including ACID, scalability, throughput, main memory usage, insert/query performance and index size etc.

Comment: It might help http://www.code-sample.com/2016/07/mongodb-advantages-disadvantages.html

Comment: Why close a question like this? As the up votes shows, it is useful. Being overzealous there. A good example of SO paradigm being pushed too far....

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Some general points on MongoDB

Pros:

- schema-less. If you have a flexible schema, this is ideal for a document store like 
  MongoDB. This is difficult to implement in a performant manner in RDBMS
- ease of scale-out. Scale reads by using replica sets. Scale writes by using sharding (auto balancing). Just fire up another machine and away you go. Adding more machines = adding more RAM over which to distribute your working set.
- cost. Depends on which RDBMS of course, but MongoDB is free and can run on Linux, ideal for running on cheaper commodity kit.
- you can choose what level of consistency you want depending on the value of the data (e.g. faster performance = fire and forget inserts to MongoDB, slower performance = wait til insert has been replicated to multiple nodes before returning)

Cons:

- Data size in MongoDB is typically higher due to e.g. each document has field names stored it
- less flexibity with querying (e.g. no JOINs)
- no support for transactions - certain atomic operations are supported, at a single document level
- at the moment Map/Reduce (e.g. to do aggregations/data analysis) is OK, but not blisteringly fast. So if that's required, something like Hadoop may need to be added into the mix
- less up to date information available/fast evolving product

I recently [blogged my thoughts](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/02/thoughts-on-mongodb-from-sql-server-dev.html) on MongoDB as someone coming from SQL Server background, so you might be interested in that (above are just some of the main points).

If you're looking for a "Is MongoDB better than RDBMS" answer - then IMHO there is no answer. NoSQL technologies like MongoDB provide an alternative, that complements RDBMS technologies. One may be better suited to a particular purpose than the other, so it's all about making a call on what is best for you for a given requirement.

Comment: +1, but I think it's important to note that mailing list responsiveness is immediate, accurate and in-depth - which is really important when the product is so fast evolving.

Comment: Good point. In my blog post I did include "Community" as one of the positives about MongoDB and also that "rapidly evolving" is also a positive. That's not to say the community for RDMBS's isn't also awesome, as it is, speaking from SQL Server POV :)

Comment: I'd say you missed a major point in citing "free" as a pro. indeed the best alternative in the RDBMS world is PostgreSQl, which is just as free and even better than SQLServer in terms of SQL standards and reliability.

Comment: @Morg - re: cost, I did say "Depends on which RDBMS..." to cover the generality of the question/answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to hear more on the benefits/costs of not having a schema and how it plays out with a practical example

Comment: (2018 UPD): Since the release of version 4.0, MongoDb finally have multi-document transaction support

Comment: For those who will read this answer, please note that this answer is since year 2011. Many things may have received an update.