# Play 2.0 (java): Is MongoDB suitable for hotel booking web app?

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, playframework-2.0

I want to implement a hotel booking system with Play framework 2.0 (Java). The app will do hotel booking with no banking transactions (credit card will be provided only as identification method to prevent fraud), user will select the desirable room and date range and the app will make the booking and update the rooms availability.

I am considering mongo over mySQL for performance reasons and also because my models will have translatable fields in a few languages which will have a lot of joins if it is in mySQL.

For Availability check I don't quite figure it out, if it is simpler in mySQL rather than mongo.

Is MongoDB suitable for that kind of web app, or I am in the wrong path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongoDB for this kind of application. I personally have some security concerns when it comes to sensitive data (i.e. credit card infirmation) as deleting the information does not automatically mean that it is unrecoverable.

From wikipedia on MongoDB: 
E-commerce. Several sites are using MongoDB as the core of their ecommerce infrastructure (**often in combination with an RDBMS** for the final order processing and accounting).

There are some very intresting articles on pros an cons on stackoverflow [Pros and cons of MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244437/pros-and-cons-of-mongodb)

If you want to learn a new NoSQL technology by all means go for it, but if you want to play it safe stick to the mysql solution. These applications (booking) often work well with BI solutions/data mining and this fact alone would make a noSql approach a no-go for me.

Answer (score 2):

Two simple statements :

- **Stick with what you know**. If you know plain SQL, go for that.
- **Premature optimization is the root of all evil.** If even before starting your application, you are already thinking of optimization, there is something terribly wrong with your way of working.